# How can I make an Extract function for embedded resources in winforms on .net core?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for long title, but I have a problem. When I make an Extract function for embedded resources in winforms on .net framework, it works properly, but exactly same function on .net core doesn't work. Why?
This function:

```
        public static void Extract(string nameSpace, string outDirectory, string internalFilePath, string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
         // winforms .net core shows here green wavy line on "assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalFilePath == "" ? "" : internalFilePath + ".") + resourceName))"
            using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalFilePath == "" ? "" : internalFilePath + ".") + resourceName))
         // and here too on "(s)"
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s))
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outDirectory + "\\" + resourceName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            w.Write(r.ReadBytes((int)s.Length));
        }
```

Comment: Which .NET Framework or .NET (Core) version?

Comment: Binary data will change when switching between different versions of Net/Core.  The class structures can change when Net versions change.  The code should work when same version of Net is used to write and then read binary data.  To get code to work with both Net and Core I would compile in Net and then target Core.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using a `BinaryReader` anyway, since you're just using it to store a byte array. It would be more normal to just copy the contents of the stream `s` into the file `fs`

Comment: @RezaAghaei .net core 5.0 and .net framework 4.8